# Parsing json into java objects with other object attribue in spring-mvc

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have an object of type element and this has an attribute of type theme. when I create a new element is represented by a theme select in the view, and the primary key is the value of the items in the select, when I send with json, spring try to create an object element and the next error is show

/element: org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.example.Theme, problem: no suitable creator method found
 at [Source: org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser$Input@dd0099; line: 1, column: 31]

this is my code in spring MVC

```
public class Element {

private String name;

private String type;

private Theme theme;

private String description;

     // Get - Set
}
```

Theme Class

```
public class Theme {

private String name;

private String description;

    // Get - Set
 }
```

Method in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestBody Element element){
    elementManager.saveElement(element);
    return "exito";
}
```

and the javascript is this

```
$("#element").submit(function() {
    var element = $(this).serializeObject();
    $.postJSON("element", element, function(data) {
    });
return false;   
});
```

i hope someone can help me.

Comment: What does your Theme class look like?

Comment: is simple POJO , already edit the post

Comment: And what about the actual JSON that is coming in?  What does that look like?

Comment: This is the json that is send to the server and receive spring , the attribute theme is the key to the object theme {"name":"rooms","type":"Doc","theme":"aglub19hcHBfaWRyCwsSBVRoZW1lGAkM","description":"They are realy big"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment containing the JSON you send the server, I would say the issue is the JSON itself.

Your server is expecting a value along the lines of this:

```
{"name":"rooms","type":"Doc","theme":{"name":"themeName", "description":"themeDescription"},"descrip‌​tion":"They are realy big"}
```

You should fetch the object theme from where it is stored, and create the proper JSON.  If the `Theme` is looked up at the client, you will need to change the Element to have a `String` theme attribute, and do the lookup on the client.